# how to passing organized parameters in a simply way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a function with N parameters and Dataframe `df` with N columns.

```
def func(param1, param2, ... paramN)
```

I want to pass each columns as parameters.

```
func(df[0], df[1], ... df[N-1])
```

How to code it in a simple way if N is large.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def func(*args):
   param1 = args[0]
   ...

df = [1,2,3]
func(*df)
```

With `*args` you can pass a variable number of positional arguments.

Answer (score 1):

- you can use `*` operator to do it

#### example:

```
def func(a,b,c):
    print(a,b,c)

func(*[1,2,3])
```

#### result:

```
1 2 3
```